# Finding element in an object by passing object as a parameter in method

Tags: java, arraylist

public class ChairTester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Chairs> chairs = new ArrayList<>();
    chairs.add(new Chairs("Rolling", "red",1523, 200.00));
    chairs.add(new Chairs("Steel","blue", 262, 150.00));
    chairs.add(new Chairs("Plastic","Biscuit",6582, 180.00));
    String key="Steel";
    System.out.println(chairs);
    System.out.println(chairs.size());

            findingChairs(chairs,"Rolling");

}

public static void findingChairs(Object obj,String key){

    for(int i=0;i<((ArrayList<Chairs>) obj).size();i++){
        System.out.println("Get index method "+((ArrayList<Chairs>) obj).get(i));
        if(((ArrayList<Chairs>) obj).get(i).getType().contentEquals(key)){
            System.out.println("Chair is found");
        }   
    }


}
```

}

if(((ArrayList) obj).get(i).getType().contentEquals(key))--

can we improve this format of coding,where in when sending an object to an another method will not require type casting. instead we can directly access the size and the element in the code.

getType method is getter method from another class of the code

Answer (score 2):

`.indexOf(elem)` returns the index in your arraylist of `elem`.

You want `.get(index)` which returns the element at index.

You're getting -1 because you are asking the arraylist to tell you the index of some number `i`, which is not in the arraylist. -1 means "not found."

Answer (score 1):

```
**get(index)**
```

The get() method of ArrayList in Java is used to get the element of a specified index within the list
**Returns** : 
**It returns the element at the specified index in the given list.**

while

```
**indexOf(elem)**
```

This method of ArrayList in Java is used to get the index of a specified element within the list
**Returns** : 
**It returns the index i.e. int of the specifies element in the given list.**
if not found return **-1**

while